# Collision detection between two Rect in android

Tags: java, android, collision-detection, accelerometer, rect

i have draw two rectangles over a canvas using `canvas.drawRect(top,left,right,bottom)` note that one of the rectangles is static and the other is moving using the android accelerometer.

1. now i want to detect the collision between those two rectangles

i tried lots of ways but they are not perfect the two rectangles overlaps sometimes so what is the perfect way to detect the collision between them.

that's what i tried 
hero  is the moving triangle
maze Component is the static rectangle

```
            if ((hero.top >= mazeComponent.top)
                && (hero.top <= mazeComponent.bottom)
                && (hero.left <= mazeComponent.right)) {
            collision = true;
        }
        if ((hero.bottom >= mazeComponent.top)
                && (hero.bottom <= mazeComponent.bottom)
                && (hero.right >= mazeComponent.left)) {
            collision = true;
        }
        if ((hero.left >= mazeComponent.left)
                && (hero.left <= mazeComponent.right)
                && (hero.top <= mazeComponent.bottom)) {
            collision = true;
        }
        if ((hero.top >= mazeComponent.top)
                && (hero.top <= mazeComponent.bottom)
                && (hero.left >= mazeComponent.left)) {
            collision = true;
        }
        if ((hero.left >= mazeComponent.left)
                && (hero.left <= mazeComponent.right)
                && (hero.top >= mazeComponent.top)) {
            collision = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Java/Android Rect and Rectangle objects have an [intersect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#intersects(android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Rect)) method that could be used to test for a collision

Comment: this function detects the collison yes, but the two rectangles still overlaps .. i want to prevent the moving one from merging into the static one !

Comment: how is the moving rectangle actually moving? repeatedly redrawn in a constant loop? if so, couldn't you just test for an intersection before the redraw? if new position will intersect don't redraw?